# Error in displaying a double value in a PlainText widget

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

[UPDATE]

This is my code:

```
double tmp=0;

double A=4.87149e+07;
double B=10;
double C=5.29e-06;
...

double sum=0;
ofstream M2;
M2.open("C:/capture/M2.doc");
for (i=0;i<916;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<916;j++)
    {
            tmp=A*B*C;
            sum= sum+tmp;
            M2 << sum << "\n";
    }
}
```

'm having what is above:

When I print the sum, it gives me a NaN result.

When I omitted the C from the sum formula, it gives me a non Nan result. Thus, I believe that the compiler is pretending that it's about a +oo/-oo multiplication (A which is so big, and C which is so small), which is not the case!

I,m dealing with important data like that.

I want to print the result at the end in a TextEdit:

```
plainTextEdit->setPlainText(QString::number(sum));
```

As soon as I reach exactly half of the i count loop (458), and j (458), the values of the Sum become equal to -1.#IND

How to handle that?

Comment: I tried your code with printf, it's printed 2577.02. Why don't you try the same with your compiler? Whatever your problem is I don't think it's what you say it is. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: @john I'm even trying to save the result in a doc file. I'm getting something like: -1.#IND  ????

Comment: Is the code in the question _the actual code_ you are running? The `sum` variable is badly named, because it is not a sum. So I'm suspecting that there are more (maybe badly named) variables in play, and the sum you are displaying is not the sum (product, in fact) you have calculated.

Comment: Let me show you how did I do exactly:

Comment: ofstream M2;

M2.open("C:/M2.doc");

tmp=A*B*C;
sum= sum+tmp;M2 << sum << " ";

Comment: And what is the value of sum before that? My guess is that it is uninitialized. You really should edit your question and show all code concerning those variables.

Comment: Note that if you declare variable like this: `double sum;` the value of `sum` is _not_ 0.

Comment: @Roku I have just updated my code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: `C:/capture/M2.doc`?? Windows will interpret it as a microsoft office document.

Comment: Well, that code works for me. You should run the program in debugger and try to find where things go wrong.

Comment: @UmNyobe Yes Windows has well interpreted the file and it's storing the values as it should be.

Comment: @Roku as for the debugging, the values are becoming -1.#IND as soon as i=458 and j=458 (right in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

Running the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double tmp=0;

    double A=4.87149e+07;
    double B=10;
    double C=5.29e-06;

    double sum=0;
    std::ofstream M2;
    M2.open("M2.doc");
    for (int i=0;i<916;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<916;j++)
        {
                tmp=A*B*C;
                sum= sum+tmp;
                M2 << sum << "\n";
        }
        qDebug() << sum;
    }
}
```

Yields:
(lines 1-10 of M2.doc)

```
2577.02
5154.04
7731.05
10308.1
12885.1
15462.1
18039.1
20616.1
23193.2
25770.2
```

...
(lines 209760-209770)
209764 is where i = 458 and j = 458

```
5.40555e+008
5.40558e+008
5.4056e+008
5.40563e+008
5.40566e+008
5.40568e+008
5.40571e+008
5.40573e+008
5.40576e+008
5.40579e+008
5.40581e+008
```

...
(lines 839047 to 839056 aka the end)

```
2.16224e+009
2.16224e+009
2.16224e+009
2.16225e+009
2.16225e+009
2.16225e+009
2.16225e+009
2.16226e+009
2.16226e+009
2.16226e+009
```

I opened the file in Notepad++ because MS Word struggles with such long files.
`tmp` is probably optimized by the compiler to act almost exactly like a constant: `2577.02`, or if you use printf you can see some additional precision pretty easily: `2577.018210` .  The `qDebug()` line yields similar answers to the terminal.

[Google's calculator output](https://www.google.com/search?q=4.87149e%2b07%2a5.29e-06%2a10&aq=f&oq=4.87149e%2b07%2a5.29e-06%2a10)

`double` can keep track of a huge range of values:

```
#include <limits>
//...
printf("%g\n", std::numeric_limits<double>::min());
printf("%g\n", std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
```

Prints out

```
2.22507e-308
1.79769e+308
```

With my setup.

I hope that helps.